# Flash breaking when in webpage and only works if JS is turned off

Tags: html, flash

Problem is that the flash movie is not working when this is within the CMS (Custom Smarty/PHP/Zend). I have totally ran out of ideas with this an pulling my hair out.

- [Working static HTML page with flash:](http://www.equi-trek.com/calculator/)
- [CMS page with flash:](http://www.equi-trek.com/finance.html)
- [XML:](http://equi-trek.com/webapp/templates/flash/bands.xml)
- [Flash:](http://equi-trek.com/webapp/templates/flash/Peregrine-Equi-Trek-Finance-Calculator-247x510.swf)

To fix a problem with the XML file originally not being read in I had to add a .htaccess to: /templates/flash

```
RewriteEngine Off
<FilesMatch "\.(swf|flv|xml)$">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

- If you turn off JS the code inside the noscript will display the flash movie but looks like it is not reading the XML file.
- If you access the flash movie directly it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
<script language="javascript" src="/webapp/templates/js/AC_RunActiveContent.js" />
```

to

```
<script language="javascript" src="/webapp/templates/js/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
```

`<script>` tags don't self-close.

Comment: Wicked this solved the problem of the flash movie not displaying